'exports is not defined' error when using crypto in svelte kit
Attempting to use node crypto in a server file in sveltekit, and getting the following error:
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at xxx/node_modules/.pnpm/crypto-browserify@3.12.0/node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js:3:1
    at instantiateModule (file:///xxx/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.2.10_@types+node@20.12.7_sass@1.75.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DkOS1hkm.js:55036:15)

import { SLACK_APP_TOKEN, SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET } from '$env/static/private'
import { createHmac } from 'node:crypto'

export const POST: RequestHandler = async ({ request }) => {
    const timestamp = request.headers.get('X-Slack-Request-Timestamp')
    const signature = request.headers.get('X-Slack-Signature')
    const body = await request.text()
    const hmac = createHmac('sha256', SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET) // using here
    const [version, hash] = signature.split('=')
    const base = `${version}:${timestamp}:${body}`
    hmac.update(base)
    const calculated = `${version}=${hmac.digest('hex')}`
    if (hash !== calculated) {
        return error(401, 'Invalid signature')
    }



    /** rest of code */
}

My understanding is that this should work fine since it's just out of the box nodejs.
for what it's worth here is my vite config:
const config: UserConfig = {
    plugins: [sveltekit(), nodePolyfills()],
    build: {
        commonjsOptions: {
            transformMixedEsModules: true
        },
        target: 'es6',
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['odoo-await']
        }
    },
    ssr: {
        noExternal: ['algoliasearch/**']
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            $lib: resolve('./src/lib'),
            $components: resolve('./src/components'),
            $data: resolve('./src/data'),
            $styles: resolve('./src/styles')
        }
    }
}


Are you using "module": "commonjs" in tsconfig.json? Does this answer your question?
